# extension that inject tag to header without any additional config

Tags: layout, blocks, extensions

I'm writing an extension for the community and I need it to inject an html tag to the head, which is not constant, eg:

```
<script>var something = "this value comes from php code";</script>
```

what's the best way to inject such a tag, to all site pages, without require the admin to do any additional config on the admin panel?

thanks!

EDIT:

Based on Bernhard Prange's answer, here's the solution for future reference (note - it just do alert don't actually inject any meaningful javascript, but you can easily put anything in the template):

**app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\inject_js.phtml**

```
<script>alert("TEST")</script>
```

**app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">

                <block type="page/html" name="dynamicJs" as="dynamicJs" template="page/html/inject_js.phtml" />

        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**app\code\community\SomeName\Test\etc\config.xml**

```
  <!-- note, DON'T put this inside the <global> tag! -->
    <frontend>
      <layout>
        <updates>
          <test>
            <file>test.xml</file>
          </test>
        </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>
```

Comment: I don't see it. Sorry.
To exclude mistakes fom the module or config.xml, put the reference tag within your theme's `layout.xml`. There it should work. If yes, you know where to look deeper into. Try what Milan says. That is often one of my mistakes ;)

Comment: ah-ha found it! the <frontend> shouldn't be inside global!  thanks mate, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make a .phtml file it which you put the content above.
- add the phtml file in you extension layout in the `default`block with `reference name="head"`

open a File in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/myExtensionLayout.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">    
      <default translate="label" module="page">
            <reference name="head">
              <block type="core/template" name="dynamicJs" as="dynamicJs" template="page/html/dynamicJs.phtml" />
               </reference>
      <default>
```

Within `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/dynamicJs.phtml` you do you thing. And add this file with it's folder structure to your extension.

Sorry to be so short but I have to walk the dog.

Comment: could you give example / be more specific?

Comment: hi Bernhard Prange thank you for the update, it was helpful. I tried to do what you said but it doesn't seem to work. do you see anything I did wrong? (added the code to the original question). thanks :)

Comment: Change the block type from `page/html` to `core/template`. Then it should work

Comment: thanks Milan, but it wasn't the problem. in the config.xml I put the <frontend> inside <global>, which was the mistake.